# Fetching sqldata into array

Tags: android

I have certain data in sqlite and want to fetch the data into an array of string, I am getting the first column successfully but cant able to fetch the next column data. Here is my code.

```
SQLiteDatabase db =  contactsdbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.openDatabase(path, factory, flags)
     int columnIndex = 1; // Whichever column your float is in
   Cursor cursor1= getData();
   String[] values=new String[cursor.getCount()+1];
   try{
   if(cursor1.moveToFirst())
   {
       for(int i=0;i<cursor1.getCount();i++ )
       {
           values[i]=cursor1.getString(columnIndex);
           //Log.i("HI", "piyush");
           Log.i("StartTime"+i, values[i]);

           cursor1.moveToNext();
       }
   }
   }
   catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
       Log.i("Exception Generated", e.toString());

   }
   String[] values1=new String[cursor.getCount()+1];
   try{
   if(cursor1.moveToNext())
   {
       for(int i=0;i<cursor1.getCount();i++ )
       {
           values1[i]=cursor1.getString(columnIndex+1);

           Log.i("EndTime"+i, values[i]);

           cursor1.moveToNext();
       }
   }
   }
   catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
       Log.i("Exception Generated", e.toString());

   }
```

Comment: Please mark correct answers; it encourages people to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not fill both arrays at once?

```
SQLiteDatabase db =  contactsdbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//db.openDatabase(path, factory, flags)
 int columnIndex = 1; // Whichever column your float is in
Cursor cursor1= getData();
String[] values=new String[cursor.getCount()+1];
String[] values1=new String[cursor.getCount()+1];
try{
if(cursor1.moveToFirst())
{
   for(int i=0;i<cursor1.getCount();i++ )
   {
       values[i]=cursor1.getString(columnIndex);
       values1[i]=cursor1.getString(columnIndex+1);
       Log.i("StartTime"+i, values[i]);

       cursor1.moveToNext();
   }
}
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
   Log.i("Exception Generated", e.toString());

}
```

But that whole thing looks kinda rubbish ... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: want to fetch the sqldata into an array, i tried this code also but again i am able to fetch the column 1 data in both the arrays.want to fetch the next column data into value1 array.

Comment: I think the value of columnIndex is not incremented in second array values1[] i tried a lot but even give static value 2 in values1[i]=cursor1.getString(2);
still not able to fetch the second column data into values1 again it showing the column1 data.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call moveToFirst() on the Cursor again before you can start reading the second column.

Specifically the second `if` should be:

`if (cursor1.moveToFirst())`

**Edit** - usually data is in a database for a reason: you don't want to fetch it all into memory in one big array most of the time.

Could you be looking for a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) and [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) combination to display the data in a list?

Comment: yah actually but my boss want to show the data into table layout manner and for these i have to first fetch the data into an array to show it into table layout.

Comment: i tried the below code also but again the second array is fetching the first column data.

Comment: your query might be wrong then. Are you sure you are actually getting columns with different data?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the column values by their column name.

```
Cursor cursor = ...
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
         values[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("columnName"));
         values1[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("otherColumnName"));
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

where "columnName" and "otherColumnName" are the names of the columns of your table which you want to fill into the arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your reply got the solution.Above code is correct i was doing some foolish things with the data part.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cur = db.query(TABLENAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        int a[] = new int[100];
```

`for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++)
    {
        a[i] = cur.getInt(0);

        cur.moveToNext();

    }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to return all the data in the table in list. But, it is not working.
I have called this method from `CheckData` class which in turn is called by main class via `intent`.

```
public List<String[]> selectAll()
{
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Cursor cursor = db
      .query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    int x = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            String[] b1 = new String[]
            {
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2)
            };
            list.add(b1);
            x = x + 1;
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

My database contains 3 columns - `id`(integer primary key), `symbol`(text) and `company_name`(text). My database name is `AppDB` and table name is `scrip`.